# Evaluate("1") gives error 438

Tags: vba, excel

I have few "Why?"s about evaluate...

```
Sub TestEvaluate()
Dim Tag As String
Tag = "5"
Tag = Evaluate(Tag) 'works fine

Tag = "1"
Tag = Evaluate(Tag) 'error 438 wrong property or method(-> my 1st "Why?")
```

But ok i can handle it:

```
Tag = "1"
Tag = [Tag] 'works fine
```

Now I need to evaluate a property of some object:

```
Dim Object As cObject
Set Object = New cObject
Object.pProperty = "5"
Tag = Evaluate(Object.pProperty) 'Works fine
```

And again the same problem as above:

```
Object.pProperty = "1"
Tag = Evaluate(Object.pProperty) '438 wrong property or method
```

But now i'm traped, becouse:

```
Tag = [Object.pProperty] 'generates error 13 type mismatch(-> my 2nds "Why?")
```

Is there some solution without the need to use a new variable?

```
Dim TempTag As String
TempTag = Object.pProperty
Tag = [TempTag] 'everything fine again

End Sub
```

i found out, in my case VBA.Evaluate("1") generates an object according to

```
debug.print VBA.VarType(evauate("1"))
```

It`s just a bug? (win8.1 xl2007)

Comment: Can't reproduce (XL2010 Win7)

Comment: Results of `Evaluate` are not necessary a string. Use different variant for output and string for input to `Evaluate`.

Comment: Dim Tag As String
    Tag = "1"
    Dim vrTag As Variant
    vrTag = Evaluate(Tag) 'err438 wrong property or method

Comment: @Hephaistos [Error 438](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251370(v=office.14).aspx), btw can't reproduce this

Comment: The second example should read `cObject.pProperty` not `Object.cProperty`

Comment: `Object` is a reserved keyword in VBA and should never be a variable name!!!

Comment: Thx a lot for your answers! y, i know, in my code i used cElement as the class and Element as the instance. But what i do not understand is why 'Evaluate("1")' generates an Object-type result- according 'debug.print VBA.VarType(Evaluate("1"))'

Comment: if you want a string use Tag = Cstr( ... ) , Convert-to-STRing.

Comment: can't apply for an object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put the expression into brackets and the problem disappeared; works fine now:

```
Tag = Evaluate("(" & Tag & ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better solution for me:

```
Tag = Evaluate(Tag & "+0")
```

It is a solution for the `Error 2015` when the `Tag=""` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use an equals sign (=) in the "Name" parameter string:

```
Trim(Evaluate("=1")) ' The result is 1.
Trim(Evaluate(" =1")) ' In VBA, Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. But not when string from a cell of Excel.
Trim(Evaluate("=1 ")) ' The result is 1.
Evaluate(" =1") ' Error 2015.
Trim(Evaluate("1")) ' Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.
Evaluate("1") ' Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

[image: I use this]
[image: In Excel VBA, I use it like this]

[image: In VBA, Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. But not when string from a cell of Excel.]